# Mock results of built-in Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm writing a test for a function xyz defined as:

```
export const socialShare = function( socialType ) {

    const url  = encodeURIComponent( document.URL );
    const text = encodeURIComponent( document.title );

    switch( socialType ) {
        case 'social-mail':
            return `mailto:example@email.com?subject=${text}&body=${text}\n${url}`;

        case 'social-facebook':
            return `//www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${url}&t=${text}`;

        case 'social-twitter':
            return `//twitter.com/share?text=${text}&url=${url}`;

        default:
            return '';
    }   
}
```

How can I mock the result of `encodeURIComponent( document.URL )`?
Is there a way I can mock `encodeURIComponent()` so that Jest can use the mock instead of the real one?

Comment: Use [`spyOn()`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.4/global.html#spyOn) like `spyOn('window', 'encodeURIComponent');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mock the **`encodeURIComponent`** implementation using **`jest.fn`**, like so:

```
test('Mock Encode URI component', () => {
    // Store original implementation
    const originalEncode = encodeURIComponent;

    const message = "test string ()@#$%^";
    encodeURIComponent = jest.fn(() => 'Mock Value');
    expect(yourFunction(message)).toBe('Mock Value');

    // Restore original implementation
    encodeURIComponent = originalEncode;
});
```

Your desired mock replacement function is passed to **`jest.fn`** as a parameter and can be used to let it return any value you need. Alternatively you can also use **`jest.spyOn`**, which provides you to ability to mock once only (or keep the original implementation and just track the number of times it is called).

```
test('Mock Encode URI component with Spy', () => {
    const message = "test string ()@#$%^";
    const spy = jest.spyOn(global, 'encodeURIComponent').mockImplementationOnce(() => 'Mock Value');
    expect(yourFunction(message)).toBe('Mock Value');
    expect(yourFunction(message)).toBe('test%20string%20()%40%23%24%25%5E');
});
```

Rather than providing a mock implemention it is also possible to just mock the return value, like so:

```
test('Mock Encode URI component with Spy and Return Value', () => {
    const message = "test string ()@#$%^";
    const spy = jest.spyOn(global, 'encodeURIComponent').mockReturnValueOnce('Mock Value');
    expect(yourFunction(message)).toBe('Mock Value');
});
```

You can read more here: [Jest Mock Functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions)